# XMPP hostname issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I am working with Openfire and xmpp in iOS, i can't get the connection done, here is my code:

```
[self.xmppStream setHostName:@"openfire.example.net"];
[self.xmppStream setHostPort:5222];
```

I am recieving the message Unable to connect to server. Check xmppStream.HostName.

I checked my openfire configuration and it is:

server name: openfire.example.net

but there is too Host Name: Decuirs-MacBook-Pro.local

what is the correct name for configuration? Also i have 2 pre created users:

jdecuirm@openfire.example.net but i am not reaching openfire, hope you can help.

**EDIT:**

Hi all, y entered to openfire.xml configuration file and i only have this:

```
-->
<!-- root element, all properties must be under this element -->
<jive> 
  <adminConsole> 
    <!-- Disable either port by setting the value to -1 -->  
    <port>9090</port>  
    <securePort>9091</securePort> 
  </adminConsole>  
  <locale>en</locale>  
  <!-- Network settings. By default, Openfire will bind to all network interfaces.
      Alternatively, you can specify a specific network interfaces that the server
      will listen on. For example, 127.0.0.1. This setting is generally only useful
       on multi-homed servers. -->  
  <!--
    <network>
        <interface></interface>
    </network>
    -->  
  <connectionProvider> 
    <className>org.jivesoftware.database.EmbeddedConnectionProvider</className> 
  </connectionProvider>  
  <setup>true</setup> 
</jive>
```

Does this part has something to do why i can't connect to xmpp? Hope you can help.

Comment: Does openfire.example.net resolve to the IP address of your server ? Ie. If you go into terminal (Mac) or command prompt (windows) and type "ping openfire.example.net" do you get a response from your server?  Simply entering a host name into the config file isn't enough. It needs to be in DNS as well

Comment: Hi i did ping to openfire.chatme.net and it is sending data Paul, this is what i get when ping 64 bytes from 72.52.4.91: icmp_seq=0 ttl=247 time=716.578 ms
64 bytes from 72.52.4.91: icmp_seq=1 ttl=247 time=110.587 ms
64 bytes from 72.52.4.91: icmp_seq=2 ttl=247 time=131.038 ms
64 bytes from 72.52.4.91: icmp_seq=3 ttl=247 time=108.077 ms

Comment: Then you should check that you can connect to the server use "telnet openfire.chatme.net 5222" if you don't get a successful connection then it could be a firewall or your server isn't running

Comment: Hi paul, i checked the panel in settings and it says running, but the telnet indeed did not work. how con i check about the firewall? it also affects if i am doing it locally? Thanks for reply Paul

Comment: Hi paul, i recently checked the firewall configuration and it is deactivated. What can i do now? Thanks for your replies.

Comment: @Paulw11 I am developing a hybrid app which uses Openfire server for chat purpose. When I tried connecting to the server through ios simulator it works fine (may be because of LAN connectivity). But when I do it using ios real device(WIFI Connection), it just shows connecting but never connects. I followed your steps in terminal and it shows connected. So, I guess there is no issue from firewall side. Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 2):

In a proper configured environment you should only specify JID and password and **never** touch hostname and port. All required information should be fetched via DNS queries.

But in your setup: `openfire.example.net` is a server name, but why you write non-existant server name? How client will find server? Yes, you can call `setHostName:@"Decuirs-MacBook-Pro.local"` and if this name is publicity visible in your local network (and only in local network) - it will connect. Also you can use your local IP, e.g. `192.168.1.2` as host name.

Comment: Hi vitalyster in fact i did connected with Decuirs-Macbook-Pro.local, but now that i am working with an iOS device, i have the issue that it is not connecting, how do you recommend me to configure the openfire server so it can be reachable? I will appreciate your advices!

Comment: @user3741129 you should understand how TCP/IP and DNS works:
1) openfire is a TCP server and it "listening" for connections on machine IP
2) DNS server helps to find required IP by name
How you are want to find server, via local Wifi or 3G network? 
If you want to access your server from 3G or any other public internet connection, you should have public IP address and DNS records first of all.

Comment: Well, for the moment for testing could it be local via wifi? you are totally right, and to have a public IP address i should hire a service or something? it is really that i am not a server side programmer vitalyster! so every kind of help you give me will be very appreciated

Comment: For local wifi connection all you need is set host name to local IP of your openfire's machine, check `sudo ifconfig` output on your Mac, 192.168.1.2 or something like this.

Comment: Hi i did the command and i can see the ip address, by doing local you mean make that ip static in my mac?

Comment: Local IP is IP from 192.168.x.x or 172.16.x.x or 10.x.x.x subnet which accessible only from local network. No need to make static, your router most time will give you the same IP, or you can check if it is changed and change it in the code.

Comment: Ok! so i changed the sethostname: from xmpp framework configuration and instead of local i used my mac ip address! you are awesome! and when the time comes and i need to change it to be accesible via 3g Network vita? what should i do?!

Comment: Then you need a public IP, in fact you already have one from your Internet Service Provider, and this IP assigned to your router every time it connects to the internet. You can check it via every website like "what is my ip". But to access openfire on your Mac you need Port Forwarding on the router, which means "when connection come from internet to port 5222 - redirect it to this Mac local ip and 5222 port" for example.

Comment: Wow thanks! Another code angel i found here! your help was great!! one more question vita!, i have a login view, but when i reset application it pops log in again, not the tableview with populated friends! how can i avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

One may setup a private xmpp server for internal testing on their local network. The xmpp domain of the server may be something like "testing.mycompany.com",but since the server is internal, an IP (192.168.1.22) is used as the hostname to connect.

Proper connection requires a TCP connection to the IP (192.168.1.22),but the xmpp handshake requires the xmpp domain (testing.mycompany.com).

```
[xmppStream setHostName:@"192.168.1.22"];
[xmppStream setHostPort:5222]; //Default
```